# How to make circular carousel slider changing with only one direction?

Tags: javascript, jquery

See the simple demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/1vf3dr80/

```
<body>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="users">

        <div class="user">
            First
        </div>

        <div class="user">
            Second
        </div>

        <div class="user">
            Third
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

```
.users {
margin-top: 1em;
margin: 0 auto;
position: fixed;
background-color: #fff;
top: 40px;
left: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 60px;
overflow: hidden;
border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}

.user {
    display: inline-block;
    border-top: 1px solid #ddd;
    background-color: #777;
    width: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
    position: relative;
    height: 59px;
    transition: transform .5s ease-in;
    -web-kit-transition: transform .5s ease-in;
}




 $(document).ready(function(){

    var length = $('.user').length;
    var i = 0;
    var sliders = $('.user');
    setInterval(function(){
        sliders.each(function(){
            $(this).css('transform', 'translateY(' + (i)*-100 + '%)');

        });
        if(i == length - 1) {
            i = 0;
        }
        else {
            i++
        }

    }, 1000)


});
```

As it shows, the initial direction of the slider is from top to bottom. When the last slide is presented, and the first one is about to present, the movement is reversed.

The effect I want is basically the same with this one: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel

The slider goes around and the direction never changes.

Comment: What you want is called 'Infinite scrolling' or 'wrap-around'. @wes-foster has started you off in the right direction (no pun intended).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use two classes to make one the active, and another the previous one, and set top position with animation based on that.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var length = $('.user').length;
    var i = 0;
    var sliders = $('.user');
    
    setInterval(function() {
        $('.user').removeClass('prev');
        $('.user').removeClass('active');
        sliders.each(function(index, element) {
            if (index == i - 1) { $(element).addClass('prev'); }
            else if (index == i) { $(element).addClass('active'); }
            else if (i == 0 && index == length - 1) { $(element).addClass('prev'); }
        });

        if(i == length - 1) {
            i = 0;
        }
        else {
            i++;
        }
    }, 1000);
});
```

```css
.users {
    margin-top: 1em;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: fixed;
    background-color: #fff;
    top: 40px;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 60px;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
    position: relative;
}
.user {
    display: inline-block;
    border-top: 1px solid #ddd;
    background-color: #777;
    width: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
    position: absolute;
    height: 59px;
    transition: top .5s ease-in-out;
    -web-kit-transition: top .5s ease-in-out;
    z-index: 0;
    top: 60px;
}
.user.prev {
    top: -60px;
    z-index: 10;
}
.user.active {
    top: 0;
    z-index: 20;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="users">
            <div class="user">
                First
            </div>

            <div class="user">
                Second
            </div>

            <div class="user">
                Third
            </div>

            <div class="user">
                Fourth
            </div>

            <div class="user">
                Fifth
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

It may be easier with [layerJS](http://layerjs.org),

edited your [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gili26/mfhk0sf8/3/) example. (note that I've added two External Resources)

Just add a **stage** div put a layer and add as many **frames** as you want between for the images.

The HTML would look something like this:

```
<div data-lj-type="stage">
<div data-lj-type="layer" data-lj-default-frame="image1">
    <div data-lj-type="frame" data-lj-name="image1" data-lj-neighbors.b="image2" class="frame">
        <image src="img/1.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div data-lj-type="frame" data-lj-name="image2" data-lj-neighbors.b="image3" class="frame">
        <image src="img/2.jpg" />
    </div>
</div>
```

*you can also have different types of transitions between them.

disclaimer: I work on the layerJS open source library that I used here.

Answer (score 0):

Essentially, what you'll want to do is move the elements around using jQuery. While I won't write the code for your entire carousel, here is a great method of how to implement this idea:

```
// This gets first list item and puts it after the last list item
// Add this code after each slide's transition
$('ul#carousel li:first').after($('ul#carousel li:last'));
```

*(You will need to alter this code to make it fit the style of your carousel.)*

By constantly moving the first item to the end (or vice-versa), it will create an infinite effect.